# Cannot get web service to ask me for char

Tags: java, web-services

I'm creating a web service that ask the user for 2 string values(the medicine name and the disease name) so it checks on the database for the rest of the columns(the dose), but even though I declare that the parameters are chars, the web service keeps asking for integers.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "pharmaInfoWS") public class pharmaInfoWS {
@WebMethod(operationName = "getInfo")
public Vector getInfo(@WebParam(name = "namemedicine") char namemedicine, char namedisease) {
    Vector v = new Vector();
    try{
      Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/pharmaDB");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        String sql="select namemedicine,namedisease, dosemedicine from pharmainfo where namemedicine = "+namemedicine+" and namedisease="+namedisease+"";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next())
        {
            v.addElement(rs.getString(1));
            v.addElement(rs.getString(2));
            v.addElement(rs.getInt(3));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return v;
}
```

And the result of testing the web service is this:

[image: Result]

pd: The columns on the database are declared as chars, except for the dose.

Comment: `char` is an integral type, try `String`.

Comment: Also, unless this is throw away code for a school assignment, please don't construct SQL statements that way. You're just asking for someone to steal all your data. See https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/OWASP_Top_Ten_2017/Top_10-2017_A1-Injection